# Java Array List - Facing issue while taking values from user, but unknowingly program terminating

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

I am trying to take values from user in ArrayList, I can take input for the size of ArrayList, But, when I am trying to add elements, the program is being terminating. Here is my code

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class ArrayDemo{
public static void main(String...args)throws IOException
{
    try {
        BufferedReader b=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Enter the size of array:");
        int n=Integer.parseInt(b.readLine());
        ArrayList<Integer> a=new ArrayList<Integer>(n);
        System.out.println("Enter the elements");
        for(int i=1;i<=n;i++) {
                a.add(b.read());
            }
        System.out.println(a);
            }catch(Exception e) {
        System.err.println("");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: "*but it's not working properly*" - What does that mean? Do you get a compiler error? Runtime exception? Unexpecte behaviour? Please create a [MCVE].

Comment: Unexpected behaviour

Comment: I can input the size  of Array list.But , when i am trying to add elements in it, the program is automatically terminating

Comment: I would suspect that your `try-catch` somehow takes effect. Try to `e.printStackTrace();` instead of `System.err.println("");`.

Comment: Nope - Still the program is terminating automatically.

Comment: Perhaps you should have a look at the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#read--) for the `read`  method of `BufferedReader`.

Comment: I am having the problem as below:                                                                                            Enter the size of array:
5
Enter the elements
1
2
[49, 13, 10, 50, 13]

Comment: I think you need `Integer.parseInt(b.readLine())` instead of `b.read()`.

Comment: You were reading one character on each trip around the loop: a `'1'`, a carriage-return, a line-feed, a `'2'`, a carriage-return, etc.  That's what `read()` does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use `.readLine()` also inside the loop:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            System.out.println("Enter the size of array:");

            int n = Integer.parseInt(b.readLine());

            ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<>(n);

            System.out.println("Enter the elements");

           for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
               int value = Integer.parseInt(b.readLine());
               a.add(value);
           }

            System.out.println(a);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("");
        }
    }
}
```

Running result:

```
Enter the size of array:

3

Enter the elements

2
3
4
[2, 3, 4]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Please, don't forget to mark this answer as solution if it solved your problem.